# Parse string representation of binary loaded from CSV

Tags: python-3.x, csv, shapely

I have a UTF-8 encoded CSV with a column that contains the string representation of a WKB (i.e., string representation of bytes).  I'm primarily interested in getting this string back into the original bytes, but when I read the CSV I get a string literal.

Assume that I cannot change how the data is stored in the CSV (i.e., save the column as WKT).

For example:

```
from shapely import wkb, geometry
point = wkb.dumps(geometry.Point(42.42, 42.42))
print(type(point))
print(point)
```

```
<class 'bytes'>
b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\xf6(\\\x8f\xc25E@\xf6(\\\x8f\xc25E@'
```

The printed bytes in the above snippet are saved in a CSV file.  I need to read that string from the CSV file back into the bytes it represents.

Comment: So what you get from the csv is `"b'\xa1\x23...'"`?  That is, the "b" is _inside_ the string?

Comment: Yes, the string in the CSV is as you describe.

Comment: `bytes_ = ast.literal_eval(string_of_bytes)`

Comment: Yes, using that is working perfectly :D  Thanks!